# How to omit (not to display) the function arguments using TexAct package?

Tags: xact

I try to use TexPrint command in the TexAct package, and the expression contains `Derivative[1][f][r[]], H2[t[], r[]]`etc., is it possible to avoid displaying these variables dependence`[t[], r[]]` by using TexPrint or other commands?
Since I want a concise output.

Answer (score 0):

I find Format command can apply `Format[Derivative[1][f][r[]] := Subscript["f", ",r"]`

Comment: It seems that you have already found the Format function. So what did you try with that towards your question?

Comment: one can first use Format command to print the expression result, then copy the result into the TexPrint[] to obtain a shorthand concise latex.